# Just want to know simple question in magento

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

If **5000 people log in to the Magento admin panel** (domainname.com/admin) at the same time or in the gap of 5 minutes then what will happen?

**The interviewer asked me such type of question.** If anyone has an answer then please comment on this.

Comment: Oh, I have to confess how much I like what if scenarios. I will dare to say that it could handle a login if you have the right server specifications to handle the request. Depending what the admins would do next, depending query cache, depending if everyone has its own user. My thought is that the question was more or less about to see what are your thoughts about this and the structure of Magento. I am really interested though to see someone more experienced who may had developed a scenario like or close to this.